# Which cars can best land straight?

Tags: burnout-paradise

The cars in Burnout Paradise like to steer in random directions when landing after a jump; the higher the fall, the harder it is to continue going straight.

Which cars are the most stable, and are thus suitable for landing huge jumps and keep going in a straight line?